# Are these components safe to use together?

Tags: battery-charging, battery-operated, solar-charge-controller

I am hoping that someone has some time to help me double check to make sure these components are safe to use together? Everything *seems* like it checks out, but I would really like to get a second opinion from people who likely have more experience than I do, and the last thing I want is to cause harm to anyone else or myself by way of a battery fire etc.
My plan is to reuse some 18650vt cells that I took out of a defunct drill battery and use them with a solar control board and solar panel for a solar light.
Control board: https://m.aliexpress.us/item/3256802965485773.html?spm=a2g0n.order_detail.order_detail_item.3.6662f19cgzm9E0&gatewayAdapt=glo2usa

And I have 6v solar panels with 100mA and 500mA.
I am not sure if that board would act as a protection for the 18650 cells or not and this would be a safe setup, I'm still learning about these things and really don't want to cause any of the worse case scenarios I've read/heard about.
Sorry for the long post and any help/comments/questions at all is very appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would be wary about ordering this item through AliExpress. There does not appear to be a detailed specification sheet or application note. Also, a two month shipping delay is very disappointing and frustrating. I found what looks like a much better unit with about 2 weeks free shipping from a US supplier:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/144541124962

From that web page:

[image: 18650 lipo cell solar charger]

[image: Charging profile]

Comment: Thank you for responding! I already have a few of the boards I posted about, it does say it has "overcharge protection of 4.25v and overdischarge protection of 2.8v"  I have some 3.7v lipo batteries with a protection board already on them, with lower maH. Just wasn't sure if the boards "protection" covered any  battery hooked up to it or not. Thank you for the info! I'll look into these.